# Does the glib list in the called function need to be free for deallocating memory

Tags: c, glib

I have a simple program that uses glib list where I have  a function which returns the list to the calling function

.here in the called function i have decleared another list and the list is returned to the calling function. I have freed the list in the main function but is in delimma that whether the list in the called function need to be freed for memory performance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <glib.h>

char *col_trim_whitespace(char *str)
{
  char *end;

  // Trim leading space
  while(isspace(*str)) str++;

  if(*str == 0)  // All spaces?
    return str;

  // Trim trailing space
  end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
  while(end > str && isspace(*end)) end--;

  // Write new null terminator
  *(end+1) = 0;

  return str;
}


GSList* line_parser(char *str)
{

        GSList* list = NULL;

        char *token, *remstr=NULL ;


        //use glist for glib 



        token = strtok_r(str,"\n",&remstr);





        while(token != NULL)
        {
            if(token[0] == ' ')
            {

            token = col_trim_whitespace(token);
            if(strcmp(token,"")==0)
                 {
                     token = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &remstr);
                      continue;
                  }
            }

            list = g_slist_append(list, token);
            token = strtok_r(NULL,"\n",&remstr);


        }





        return list;

}

int main()
{


 int *av,i,j,length;
 i=0;


char str[] = " this name of \n the pet is the ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff\n is \n the \n test\n program";


GSList *list1 = line_parser(str);
// printf("The list is now %d items long\n", g_slist_length(list));
 length = g_slist_length(list1);
// printf("length=%d", length);



for(j=0;j<length;j++)
{

    printf("string = %s\n",(char *)g_slist_nth(list1,j)->data);

}

g_slist_free(list1);

return 0;

}
```

Do i need to manually free glist from line_parser function?

Answer (score 0):

Like TingPing mentioned, `strtok_r` doesn't allocate any memory, so no you don't need to free it.

If you did need to free it (for example if you were to `strdup` the value from `strtok_r`) then you would most likely want to use [g_slist_free_full](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html#g-slist-free-full).

Comment: `strtok_r()` doesn't allocate memory it modifies the string in-place, so they would not need to be freed.

Comment: You're right, edited to reflect that.  If you want to add that as an answer I'll delete mine so you can get credit if the author accepts the answer.