# passing glist pointer as argument to reflect changes in list does not work

Tags: c, function, pointers, argument-passing, glib

I want to pass the glist pointer to the function so that I can get the changed  value in main function.

I have code as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <glib.h>

char *col_trim_whitespace(char *str)
{
  char *end;

  // Trim leading space
  while(isspace(*str)) str++;

  if(*str == 0)  // All spaces?
    return str;

  // Trim trailing space
  end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
  while(end > str && isspace(*end)) end--;

  // Write new null terminator
  *(end+1) = 0;

  return str;
}


void line_parser(char *str,GSList* list1)
{
    GSList* list = NULL; 
    char *token, *remstr=NULL ;

    token = strtok_r(str,"\n",&remstr);
    while(token != NULL)
        {
            if(token[0] == ' ')
            {

            token = col_trim_whitespace(token);
            if(strcmp(token,"")==0)
                 {
                     token = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &remstr);
                     continue;
                  }
            }
            list1 = g_slist_append(list1, token);
            token = strtok_r(NULL,"\n",&remstr);
        }

}

int main()
{

 int *av,i,j,length;
 i=0;

char str[] = " this name of \n the pet is the ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff\n is \n the \n test\n program";


//GSList *list1 = line_parser(str);
GSList *list1 = NULL;
line_parser(str,list1 );
// printf("The list is now %d items long\n", g_slist_length(list));
 length = g_slist_length(list1);
// printf("length=%d", length);

for(j=0;j<length;j++)
{
    printf("string = %s\n",(char *)g_slist_nth(list1,j)->data);
}

g_slist_free(list1);

return 0;
}
```

here I have a list name `list1` in the main function, then I passed `list1` as an argument to the `lineparser()` function where the list is changed appending some values. and I want to return the value to the `main()` function but without using a `return` statement as I have used the pointer reference while passing argument. but the value is not returned to the `main()` function. How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the glib list in the called function need to be free for deallocating memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792236/does-the-glib-list-in-the-called-function-need-to-be-free-for-deallocating-memor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you want to pass the address of the list pointer, and then have the parser update that variable:

```
void line_parser(char *str,GSList **list1)
{
    ...
    *list1= list;
}
```

and in main:

```
main()
{
    GSList *list1 = NULL;
    line_parser(str, &list1);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As it appears, [`g_slist_append()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html#g-slist-append) returns the *new* start pointer of the list. So, essentially, you're trying to change the `list1` value from the `line_parser()` and expecting that value to be reflected back into `main()`.

Well, that is not possible in the current form. `C` uses pass-by-value for function parameter passing, so all the arguments passed to a function are a *separate local copy* to the called function, while considering as parameters to the called function.

If you want the change to `list1`  to be reflected to `main()`, you need to use a pointer-to-pointer as the input parameter.

Something along the line of

```
 void line_parser(char *str,GSList** list1) { //and other usage
```

and

```
 line_parser(str,&list1 );
```

should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One way:

1. This line `GSList *list1 = NULL;` creates a pointer, not the `GSList` structure. You might want to allocate memory for the list using `malloc` and cast it to a `GSList`. For example, `GSList list1 = (GSList) malloc(sizeof(GSList));`
2. Then in your function `line_parser` we will need to pass a pointer `line_parser(str, &list1)`

   Remember to `free(list1)`

Another way would be to create the `GSList` on the stack. Regardless, we still pass a pointer to `line_parser`, as mentioned above.