# Do we need to free each element in the list in GLIB

Tags: c, list, memory-management, free, glib

I have been seeing this document [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-glib/).

and the code is:

```
#include <glib.h>
void print_iterator(gpointer item, gpointer prefix) {
 printf("%s %s\n", prefix, item);
}
void print_iterator_short(gpointer item) {
 printf("%s\n", item);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 GSList* list = g_slist_append(NULL, g_strdup("first"));
 list = g_slist_append(list, g_strdup("second"));
 list = g_slist_append(list, g_strdup("third"));
 printf("Iterating with a function:\n");
 g_slist_foreach(list, print_iterator, "-->");
 printf("Iterating with a shorter function:\n");
 g_slist_foreach(list, (GFunc)print_iterator_short, NULL);
 printf("Now freeing each item\n");
 g_slist_foreach(list, (GFunc)g_free, NULL);
 g_slist_free(list);
 return 0;
}
```

Here each element in the list is freed using loop. In the previous examples there is simply freeing of entire list as `g_slist_free(list);` in this example it is shown that each element in the list is freed using foreach loop.

Do we need to free each element or freeing whole list is sufficient ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the glib list in the called function need to be free for deallocating memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792236/does-the-glib-list-in-the-called-function-need-to-be-free-for-deallocating-memor)

Answer (score 4):

From: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html#g-slist-free

```
void
g_slist_free (GSList *list);
```

> Frees all of the memory used by a GSList. The freed elements are
>   returned to the slice allocator. If list elements contain
>   dynamically-allocated memory, **you should either use
>   g_slist_free_full() or free them manually first**.

So yes you have to free each element first or use **g_slist_free_full()**

Answer (score 2):

**It depends on what the list contains.**

`g_slist_free()` will only free the memory occupied by the list nodes themselves, since it doesn't know what is stored in the list (GSList is not type-safe). It will not touch the `data` pointer in the list nodes.

In your example, the list contains C strings allocated with `strdup`, so you have to free them before freeing the list nodes. However, if your list contains pointers to constant data, or the `data` field stores integers type-casted to `void*`, then you should *not* free the elements.

Generally, you have to free the elements before freeing the list if and only if the `data` pointers in the list nodes point to dynamically allocated memory: something you obtained from `malloc`, `g_malloc`, `g_new`, etc.

Comment: if i have a list containing the say 5 elements and i need to iterate each element for some manipulation and i initialized GSList *iterator of glist. Do i need to deallocate this *iterator pointer or not?

Comment: No, the iterator pointer doesn't need to be freed. You must only free each allocated element exactly once, and you did not allocate anything when you initialized the iterator - you only made a reference to already allocated elements.